# allocation and deletion of QDialogProgress

Tags: c++, qt, heap-memory, stack-memory

**should I delete** QDialogProgress pointer with `delete` or not? I have seen that pointer to QDialogProgress allocated on heap hasn't been deleted in some code. Also, should it be placed on stack? Most examples I have seen allocate QDialogProgress on stack.

```
int f(void)
{

    //The minimum and maximum is the number of steps in the operation for which this progress dialog shows progress.
    //for example here 0 and 100.
    QProgressDialog* progress = new QProgressDialog("Fetching data...", "Cancel", 0, 100);
          progress->setAutoClose(true);
    progress->setAutoReset(true);
    progress->setWindowTitle
    (QCoreApplication::translate("title",
                                 "Please wait"));
    progress->setMinimumDuration(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        //set progress value.
        progress->setValue(i);
    }

    progress->setValue(100);

    //delete progress; ???????????????? is there a leak if not?
    return 500;
}
```

Comment: You're doing everything without going back to the event loop, the dialog will never be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all depends on how you're using your progress dialog. If you only need it in one scope, then making it a pointer is pointless. But if you do make it a pointer, you can set the  Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose flag so it will be deleted automatically when it is closed.

```
QProgressDialog *dialog = new QProgressDialog;
dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

Comment: thanks. so, if there is a pointer created in some function and initialized with QProgressDialog created on heap, and I don't see setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose) and no explicit delete too - so it means this couldn't be set in other place and there is a leak, right?

Comment: so how about [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Archived:Create_progress_dialog_using_QProgressDialog) no setAttribute and no delete

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain It is added to a layout. Once the layout gets destroyed, it will handle the destruction of `QProgressDialog` on it's own. As you might already know, [child widgets are automatically destroyed by the parent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/objecttrees.html).

Comment: in this case this is not added to a layout

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain In the example you provided a link to, it is: `layout->addWidget(progress,Qt::AlignCenter);`. But in your code, you have a memory leak if you don't delete your progressdialog.